# format json response properly of csv pulled from S3 bucket

Tags: python, json, csv, amazon-s3

I have a small csv with data that looks like this:

```
  Ticker    Exchange    Date    Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
  6A        BATS    12/2/2021   0.9     0.95    0.83    0.95    1200
  6B        BATS    12/3/2021   1       1.3     0.9     1.2     1500
  6C        BATS    12/4/2021   1.2     1.3     1.1     1.1     1300
```

I am using the following code to pull latest file from bucket and print as json.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
object_list = []
bucket_name = 'bats-candles'

paginator = s3.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name)
for result in page_iterator:
    object_list += filter(lambda obj: obj['Key'].endswith('.csv'), result['Contents'])
object_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])

A = (object_list[-1]['Key'])
full_path = f"s3://{bucket_name}/{A}"
print(full_path)
print(A)

raw_df = pd.read_csv(full_path)

print(bucket_name, full_path)

df = raw_df.to_json(orient="records")

response = {
    'body': json.dumps(df, indent=4, separators=(',', ':'))
}

pretty_json = json.dumps(response)
print(pretty_json)
```

The data that I get back looks like this:

```
{"body": "\"[{\\\"Ticker\\\":\\\"6A\\\",\\\"Exchange\\\":\\\"BATS\\\",\\\"Date\\\":\\\"12\\\\/2\\\\/2021\\\",\\\"Open\\\":0.9,\\\"High\\\":0.95,\\\"Low\\\":0.83,\\\"Close\\\":0.95,\\\"Volume\\\":1200}
```

but I would like it to look like this:

```
[
        {
            "Ticker":"6A",
            "Exchange":"BATS",
            "Date":"12/2/2021",
            "Open":0.9,
            "High":0.95,
            "Low":0.83,
            "Close":0.95,
            "Volume":1200
        },
        {
            "Ticker":"6B",
            "Exchange":"BATS",
            "Date":"12/3/2021",
            "Open":1.0,
            "High":1.3,
            "Low":0.9,
            "Close":1.2,
            "Volume":1500
        },
        {
            "Ticker":"6C",
            "Exchange":"BATS",
            "Date":"12/4/2021",
            "Open":1.2,
            "High":1.3,
            "Low":1.1,
            "Close":1.1,
            "Volume":1300
        } ]
```

Can anyone suggest the proper way to achieve this? I have tried all sorts of combinations of json.dumps and json.loads but cant find the proper combination.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have serialized the JSON response in the body using `json.dumps()`

You can use the function `json.loads()` to deserialize JSON.

Try:

```
json.loads(pretty_json);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pprint
s=''' Ticker    Exchange    Date    Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
  6A        BATS    12/2/2021   0.9     0.95    0.83    0.95    1200
  6B        BATS    12/3/2021   1       1.3     0.9     1.2     1500
  6C        BATS    12/4/2021   1.2     1.3     1.1     1.1     1300'''

z=s.split('\n')
res=[]
d={}
zz=z[0].split()
for st in range(1,len(z)):
    for t in range(len(z[st].split())):
         d[zz[t]]=z[st].split()[t]
    res.append(d)
pprint.pprint(res,sort_dicts=False)
```

---

```
[{'Ticker': '6C',
  'Exchange': 'BATS',
  'Date': '12/4/2021',
  'Open': '1.2',
  'High': '1.3',
  'Low': '1.1',
  'Close': '1.1',
  'Volume': '1300'},
 {'Ticker': '6C',
  'Exchange': 'BATS',
  'Date': '12/4/2021',
  'Open': '1.2',
  'High': '1.3',
  'Low': '1.1',
  'Close': '1.1',
  'Volume': '1300'},
 {'Ticker': '6C',
  'Exchange': 'BATS',
  'Date': '12/4/2021',
  'Open': '1.2',
  'High': '1.3',
  'Low': '1.1',
  'Close': '1.1',
  'Volume': '1300'}]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i accepted your answer and modified as follows to achieve what I needed. Thanks

```
raw_df = pd.read_csv(full_path)

df = raw_df.to_json(orient="records")
parsed = json.loads(df)
parsed_w_separators = json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
print(parsed_w_separators)
```